# mediawiki nesting multiple functions (underscores)

Tags: mediawiki

I would need some help please.
I have a page in a mediawiki website which lists all the links of a category using its prefix (ex: category **AlertDialog**).

**{{Special:PrefixIndex/AlertDialog}}**

This is exactly what I need, the problem is I don't see the underscores in the returned links.

I am trying to nest multiple wikimedia functions to have the desire result. I have tried a couple of things with no luck:

```
{{#ask: [[AlertDialog:+]] }}
{{localurl:{{Special:PrefixIndex/AlertDialog}}}}
{{DISPLAYTITLE:{{Special:PrefixIndex/AlertDialog}}}}
{{PAGENAMEE:{{Special:PrefixIndex/AlertDialog}}}}
```

Any (easy) ways I can see those underscores? (**I don't have admin access, I try to do it using mediawiki functions/API**)

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Where is your underscore supposed to be? Please provide desired and current outputs!

Comment: thank you for your feedback; I have this for example: {{Special:PrefixIndex/Event}} which  outputs among other links this one: Event.ADDED TO STAGE. I would like this output: Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE

Comment: here is the link of the page: https://wiki.giderosmobile.com/index.php/All_Classes_and_more